# How to handle "polymorphic" function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Imagine I'm writing a react app, where the user can add shapes in different colors and sizes to some "workspace". Let's say we have the components `Circle` and `Square` which would have different properties to define them. As the user adds shapes, its props are added to the state of the workspace component. The workspace then draws the shapes like:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

interface ISquareProps {
    color: string;
    lineLength: number;
}

interface ICircleProps {
    color: string;
    radius: number;
}

const Square = ({lineLength}: ISquareProps) => (<div>I'm a square with line length {lineLength}</div>);
const Circle = ({radius}: ICircleProps) => (<div>I'm a circle with radius {radius}</div>);

const Workspace = () => {
    const [squares, setSquares] = useState(new Array<ISquareProps>());
    const [circles, setCircles] = useState(new Array<ICircleProps>());

    return (
        <>
            {squares.map((square) => <Square {...square} /> )}
            {circles.map((circle) => <Circle {...circle} /> )}
        </>
    );
};
```

Find an example here:

[image: Edit draw-shapes-1]

While this works fine for two different shapes it'll get cumbersome if we'll have many shapes.

What if the shapes would know how to render themselves? What about this:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

interface IShapeProps {
    color: string;
    render(): JSX.Element;
}

// ------- square -------
interface ISquareProps extends IShapeProps {
    lineLength: number;
}

const Square = ({lineLength}: ISquareProps) => (<div>I'm a square with line length {lineLength}</div>);

class SquareProps implements ISquareProps {
    public color: string;
    public lineLength: number;

    constructor(lineLength: number, color: string) {
        this.color = color;
        this.lineLength = lineLength;
    }

    public render() {
        return <Square {...this} />;
    }
}
// ------- circle -------
interface ICircleProps extends IShapeProps {
    radius: number;
}

const Circle = ({radius}: ICircleProps) => (<div>I'm a circle with radius {radius}</div>);

class CircleProps implements ICircleProps {
    public color: string;
    public radius: number;

    constructor(color: string, radius: number) {
        this.color = color;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public render() {
        return <Circle {...this} />;
    }
}
// ------- workspace -------
const Workspace = () => {
    const [shapes, setShapes] = useState(new Array<IShapeProps>());

    return (
        <>
            {shapes.map((shape) => shape.render() )}
        </>
    );
};
```

A working example is here:

[image: Edit draw-shapes-2]

Is this a feasible approach to handle "polymorphic" components with function components?
Are there alternative patterns that should be considered?

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be doing is just currying the `Shape` and `Circle` components, but from what I can see nothing in your render method actually tells the shape which shape it is.
You would need a param to that render func to decide which one it is.

A couple of improvements you could make though:

1) Something that would make more sense to me though is instead of currying it with just some "function", wrap it in a react component that is smart enough to decide.

2) Use props instead of class properties, that's what they're meant for. No reason to reassign it to a `this` variable

3) Use conditional JSX to decide which component to render based off props (you could even toggle the shapes, and they would switch as a new prop triggers a re render)

4) I don't see too much of a need to separately implement the prop interfaces you have, you can do it inline with a function component

```
export const Shape = (props: IShapeProps) => {

    public render() {
        if (this.props.shapeType === 'Square') {
           return <Square lineheight={this.props.lineheight} color={this.props.color} />;
        } else {
           return <Circle radius={this.props.radius} color={this.props.color} />;
        }  
    }
}
```